# What is the poetry equivalent of pip install -e .[dev]

Tags: continuous-integration, python-poetry

Let's say I have this:

```
extras_require={
        'dev': [
            'pytest',
            'pytest-cov',
            'coverage',
            'pre-commit'
        ],
    }
```

in my `setup.py`. In order to install these dependencies I would run: `pip install -e .[dev]`. What is the equivalent of all this in [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

under pyproject.yaml you have a section of all dev dependencies

```
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
```

you can add manually the dependencies and run `poetry install` or run the following to add it to dev only with `poetry add [dependency] --dev`

To install only the
dependencies and not including the current project, run the command with the

```
--no-root
```

Comment: What if you have even more block of separate requirements. Let's say `pip install -e .[yolo]` for example. Maybe it is not possible...

Comment: For anybody needing in depth explanation on how to handle different requirements using poetry: https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-dependencies/

Comment: The current version of poetry discourages `poetry add --dev [dependency]` and prefers, instead, `poetry add -G dev [dependency]` instead.